# Is there a link between fuel shortages in Argentina and the presidential election?

Tags: economy, oil, argentina

If you make a search on the internet with the keyword *argentina fuel shortage* you will find a lot of articles about a fuel crisis that started around the first round of the presidential election and deepened during the campaign for the run-off. The incumbent Sergio Massa blamed the suppliers, but did not explicitly accuse them of interference in the election. However this is an issue that has high impact on the voters' choice. The primary example is the [fuel crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Carter#Economy) that helped the victory of Reagan over Carter it the [presidential elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1980_United_States_presidential_election).

Of course it would be difficult to prove the crisis was made on purpose. But if it was caused by suddenly holding tight on the stocks or suddenly overselling abroad the coincidence would be suspect. Are there any data available? Do the suppliers have a (more than) reasonable explanation for the coincidence?